# May I know what exactly requireGestureRecognizerToFail will do?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

Can any one let me know what exactly the below code line will do? I have referred [Apples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail%3a) documentation but didn't get the exact picture about this,

```
[scrollview.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeRightGesture];
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When user make a right swipe gesture then pan gesture will be failed (ignored).

Answer (score 3):

An example，`[_singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:_doubleTap]`,  when you want a single-tap gesture require that a double-tap gesture fail. Double-tap includes two single taps, so if no `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` single-tap gesture delegate method may invoke twice.

So here, swipe gesture may trigger pan gesture, then will invoke panGestureRecognizer delegate method while you are swiping actually.

If add `[panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeRightGesture]` , once swipeRightGesture transitions to UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized or UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, `panGestureRecognizer` transitions to UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed immediately.

And only swipeRightGesture haven't transited to above RecognizerStates, there is possible for panGestureRecognizer to respond, transited to UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan,  and invoke panGestureRecognizer delegate method.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is only partially correct...

[According to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail:) for `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:`

> The state that the receiver transitions to depends on what happens
>   with otherGestureRecognizer [the second referenced gesture recognizer]:
>
> - If otherGestureRecognizer transitions to UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed, the receiver transitions to its normal
>     next state.
> - If otherGestureRecognizer transitions to UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized or UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan,
>     the receiver transitions to UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed.

This means that in the following code:

```
[scrollview.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeRightGesture];
```

When the user makes a swipe gesture, the pan gesture will only fail if that swipe gesture proceeds as normal. If that swipe gesture fails however, the pan gesture will proceed instead.