# iOS Disable Pan when Swipe

Tags: ios, swipe, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer, pan

I want to disable pan gesture when swipe and disable swipe if I pan but I ended up activate both whether I pan or swipe. Is there anything I have amiss?

```
#pragma mark - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate methods
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    [otherGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:gestureRecognizer];

    NSLog(@"added failure requirement to: %@", otherGestureRecognizer);
}

if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    [[BTHomeViewController sharedInstance].revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:gestureRecognizer];
}

if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    [left requireGestureRecognizerToFail:[BTHomeViewController sharedInstance].revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    [right requireGestureRecognizerToFail:[BTHomeViewController sharedInstance].revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi shoujo_sm, this answer helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928023/may-i-know-what-exactly-requiregesturerecognizertofail-will-do as an idea how you might solve the problem. Even tough on the end I used the UIScrollView property
delaysContentTouches for my case. Here what the documentation says about this property:"If the value of this property is YES, the scroll view delays handling the touch-down gesture until it can determine if scrolling is the intent. If the value is NO , the scroll view immediately calls touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:. The default value is YES."

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to combine these 2 gestures. The problem is you usually want the pan gesture to execute instantly (which it does) but the swipe gesture takes a bit time to be recognised since the user must drag his finger some path.

Anyway there are generally 2 procedures you can consider:

First is making both gestures recognisable at the same time (which you already did). What you need to add is when the swipe gesture is recognised simply remove the pan gesture calls. To do this all you need to do is `panGesture.enabled = NO; panGesture.enabled = YES;` this 2 lines are simply called one after another and the gesture will not trigger until another touch has begin.

Second is waiting to see if the swipe will be recognised. To do that it is easiest to replace the pan gesture with a long press gesture. Note that the long press gesture acts exactly as the pan gesture except you may set it an appropriate `minimumPressDuration` (the duration you expect the swipe will be recognised in) and an appropriate `allowableMovement` which should be very large in your case.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your tips. I am aiming to do things like app "The New York Times". I am using the SWRevealViewController so changing to long press might a bit challenging to me.

Comment: How is that so? As I said replacing a pan gesture with a long press will act the same as the pan gesture if you set some very low minimumPressDuration. No other code should be changed by this. Anyway looking at your question again there seem to be a bit of a contradiction: Disabling swipe when panned is not possible as it is since the pan gesture will trigger as a part of a swipe gesture. If possible you might want to consider implementing a custom gesture control using touches methods. That is not an easy task though.

Comment: If I use long press then I will not able to detect which direction user swipe. In what condition should the I set YES/NO to panGesture?

Comment: Ah no, you misunderstood. You keep the swipe gestures but replace the pan gesture with a long press. In this case the long press will wait a bit to see if the swipe was detected and trigger if only if not, then cancel the swipe gestures. So in this case you should remove the delegate methods. YES/NO is used in the situation you already have: Once the swipe gesture is detected you call that on your pan gesture recogniser so it stops recognising until the next gesture is triggered. What I posted are 2 different procedures, you can choose one but not both.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I played a lot with the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate but no luck.

What i did was decide when a "pan" should be considered a "swipe" based on the velocity and the gesture finish. Therefore, if the user starts panning and the velocity is less than a certain value, continue, if the user pan fast and finishes the gesture, then trigger the "swipe".

This worked for my business requirements. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create relationship with gesture to make possible:

```
panGesture.require(toFail: swipeGesture)
```